# Parsing XML File in Objective-C

Tags: ios, xml

I have xml file which I have to parse it. I'm following a youtube tutorials for it. I'm showing the parsed data from tags in a table view controller, But when i run the app no data is shown there, the table view controller is just empty. My code for parsing the file is this,

```c
#import "QuestionParser.h"
#import "Question.h"

@interface QuestionParser()
@property NSXMLParser *parser;
@property NSString *element;
@property NSString *currentxref;
@property NSString *currenttext;
@property NSString *currentprompt;
@property NSString *currentexplanation;
@property NSString *currenttext1;

-(id)initWithArray:(NSMutableArray *)questionArray{

    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        self.questionArray = questionArray;
    }

    return self;
}

-(void)parseFile{

    NSURL *url= [[NSBundle mainBundle]URLForResource:@"test" withExtension:@"xml"];
    self.parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    self.parser.delegate=self;
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
    attributes:(NSDictionary<NSString *,NSString *> *)attributeDict{
    self.element = elementName;
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
    if ([self.element isEqualToString:@"xref"]) {
        self.currentxref = string;
    }

    else if ([self.element isEqualToString:@"text"]){
        self.currenttext = string;
    }

    else if ([self.element isEqualToString:@"prompt"]){
        self.currentprompt = string;
    }

    else if ([self.element isEqualToString:@"explanation"]){
        self.currentexplanation = string;
    }

    else if ([self.element isEqualToString:@"text"]){
        self.currenttext1 = string;
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"question"]) {
        Question *ques= [[Question alloc]initWithName:_currentxref text:_currenttext prompt:_currentprompt explanation:_currentexplanation text1:_currenttext1];

        [self.questionArray addObject:ques];
    }
    self.element = nil;
}
```

This is how I'm loading data in datasource,

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.questionArray.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    Question *ques=self.questionArray[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text=ques.xref;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",ques.prompt];

    return cell;
}
```

My xml file is this,
[image]

Comment: It's unclear. The XMLParsing is async. Did it finished? Do you reload your tableView?

Comment: actually this is my first time with xml , i myself not got it how can i get this. @Larme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method will execute after complete XML parsing. In this method reload the table view data.

```c
-(void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser{
    // When the parsing has been finished then simply reload the table view.
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

If you want anything please follow this tutorial: https://www.appcoda.com/parse-xml-and-json-web-service/

Comment: Bro i have to parse the above file. I'm coonfuse in this that first i have to get  QF tag value and than Question? @Faysal Ahmed

Comment: Follow the tutorial then you can get how to parse XML using Objective C.

Comment: Bro in the tutotials it is taking xml file from a url  but i have my own file which i have added into my project i have to take data from there. @Faysal Ahmed